# Oracle apex стоит ли им собирать ui?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-apex

Добрый день. Стоит вопрос на чем собрать веб приложение, и коллега посоветовал Oracle APEX, так как там не надо париться с интерфейсом. На сколько это оправдано? Плюсы и минусы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работаю апекс-разработчиком пару лет, могу сказать следующее. В первую очередь апекс хорош как среда разработки для тех, кто с вебом соприкасался только как пользователь.

**Плюсы:**

- Можно разрабатывать простенькие приложения, не умея программировать вообще (примерно как в MS Access)
- Можно разрабатывать достаточно сложные приложения, зная только SQL и PL/SQL
- Можно значительно улучшить клиентскую часть с минимальными познаниями HTML/CSS/JavaScript, можно (иногда только с помощью ломика и какой-то матери) интегрировать сторонние JS компоненты

**Минусы:**

- Всё очень плохо с контролем версий (какие-то минимальные возможности есть, но это не то, что имеет право на существование в 2018-м году)
- Нетривиальные интерфейсные вещи иногда требуют нетривиальных действий
- Некоторые CSS классы и шаблоны слишком жестко захаркодены, их сложно кастомизировать
- Через одно место сделана поддержка многоязычных приложений

Ну а в целом - скорее рекомендую, чем нет.

Comment: @Dmitriy если есть плюсы значит надо пробовать!а минусы всегда и у всег о найдутся